# I couldn't calculate Population stability index in R

Tags: r, spss

I want to calculate of PSI between model devolopment data and  out of time data by pd bucket.And I want to get approximetly same bucket in this calculation.For this I searched for optimal binning methodolgy and faced with R packages-smbinning.psi. But when I tried to use this function "x mmust be factor" error appeared although I have already run as.factor function. Have you any solution about this binning or how to handle this problem in this case

I have already tried to test optimal binning in SPSS.But I couldn't understand how to use this for my case

## Load library and its dataset

````
library(smbinning)
df23$period<-as.factor(df23$period)
df23$...6<-as.factor(df23$...6)
class(df23$`uncalibrated pd`)

attach(df23)
# Check stability for income
smbinning.psi(df=df23,y='period',x='...6')```

Error in smbinning.psi(df = df23, y = "period", x = "...6") : 
  x must be formatted as factor
````

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly. smbinning.psi does not allow the name of x to contain a dot.

Comment: df23$Gender<-as.factor(df23$Gender)

# Check stability for income
``smbinning.psi(df=df23,y='period',x='Gender') ``
Also this case return error
``str(df23$Gender)``
Output:Factor w/ 2 levels "f","m": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...

Comment: Could you try df23$period not as a factor. Only x is required to be a factor.

Comment: problem is same